# How to displaying Float/Double in meaningful form in Android

Tags: android, floating-point, double

I am trying to make a BMI application. When I run the application the BMI values are displayed in numeral form that I don't understand. I have tried both Float and Double type but results are same.

For example: 
Height (m): 2
Weight (Kg): 100
BMI is displayed as : **2.0E-4**  instead of 25

The part of the code that effects this is:

```
        String  editText1= height_field.getText().toString();
        String  editText2= weight_field.getText().toString();   
        try {  // Parse string to int
           double height = Double.parseDouble(editText1);
           double weight = Double.parseDouble(editText2);
           double bmi_result = (weight/(height*height));
           String bmi_text = Double.toString(bmi_result);
           display.setText(bmi_text);
         System.out.println("OnClick: computeButton is clicked");
       }
       catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
           alert.show();   // Show error alert
```

Comment: I suspect you've got the height and weight fields the wrong way round. You've got 2/(100*100) instead of 100/(2*2)

Comment: Also if you need specific formatting, the NumberFormatter or DecimalFormatter are great helper classes to spit out nice strings from various numeric classes http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

To answer your original question, you should be using [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), something like:

```
 DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
 display.setText(formatter.format(bmi_result));
```

Will force the result to be in the format of two digits followed by two decimal points, the table in the link above shows how to generate that.

However, since 2.0E-4 is 0.0002, I think Jon Skeet's comment is correct: You're doing your math operation wrong, since the value you're printing is a very small fraction of 25 :)

I'd recommend using `Log.v()` to print out your math operation before you actually do it, so you can see what the values of `weight` and `height` actually are, I highly doubt they're correctly set at what you described in the question.

Comment: Thanks guys the in the layout the Height and Weight fields got jumbled up. And that is why I was getting wrong values..

And thanks for "DecimalFormat"